# Remove space between detail and last page footer

Tags: jasper-reports

How i can remove the space between detail and last page footer in *JasperReports*?

I need to remove the white space between them

I use this code for lastpagefooter

```xml
<lastPageFooter>
    <band height="187">
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="125" y="0" width="68" height="20" uuid="d7bc9c8a-c20b-4f79-8515-639609ead0cc"/>
            <box>
                <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
            </box>
            <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font size="14"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[المجموع : ]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="35" y="0" width="90" height="20" uuid="4b93f507-3e79-4ba7-99ce-d65b64a1a78b"/>
            <box>
                <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
            </box>
            <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font size="14"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{Totals}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField evaluationTime="Report">
            <reportElement x="23" y="167" width="40" height="20" uuid="c0c0de0b-7bb5-4133-bf5e-dfe51f91dac4"/>
            <box rightPadding="2"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
    </band>
</lastPageFooter>
```

http://www.gulfup.com/?lV8MpF

This is the file

Comment: Try to maximize band height of Last Page footer band.

Comment: Provide whole jrxml file for better understanding.

Comment: Need to look at complete jrxml, to understand what you are doing, and for us to help you.

Comment: http://www.gulfup.com/?lV8MpF

Comment: when you maximize the band height of last page footer the detail band will removed in the last page

Answer (score -1):

I just change the propriety of report Ignore pagination  to true

```xml
<jasperReport ... isIgnorePagination="true" ...>
```

The problem in this case that i can't use break
I want to break to a new page when the number of the rows

finally, I use group footer and i add the total in it